# Как подключить многопоточность для одной функции с разными аргументами?

Tags: python, многопоточность, threading

Есть одна функция, которую нужно вызывать одновременно с тремя разными аргументами, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать на примере многопоточности в python.

```
def fun(a):
   p = a + 10
   return p


fun(4)
fun(10)
fun(15)
```

Comment: А где ваши попытки? На просторах интернета масса примеров.

Comment: Спасибо, Серёжа, за совет, даже не знаю чтобы я без тебя делал. Оказывается, моё решение есть на просторах интернета, офигеееть. По твоим рассуждениям, Серёжа, этот сайт вообще не нужен, так как любое решение есть на просторах интернета. Представляю сколько у тебя наград в номинации "Советчик года".

Comment: на этот вопрос масса ответов даже на этом сайте. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=threading.

Comment: Спасибо. Я уже нашёл решение.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1206877/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-threading-%d0%b8-multiprocessing Для общего развития, чтоб понимать уместность применения threading

Comment: Спасибо! Обязательно ознакомлюсь.

Comment: @КириллМаколов на будущее, пожалуйста, воздержитесь от переходов на личности, здесь это не принято. Просьба показать ваши попытки (ведь интернет полный примеров) следует из первой же рекомендации по составлению [хорошего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), потому не является какой то грубостью в ваш адрес. Из личного опыта - полнота вопроса и вежливость кратно повышают шансы получить ответ на интересную вам тему.

Comment: @tym32167 Я вас услышал, многоуважаемый товарищ, спасибо за совет! Вы знаете как я ценю их. Впредь, благодаря вам, я буду теперь знать, что здесь не принято переходить на личность, ведь  полнота вопроса и вежливость кратно повышают шансы получить ответ на интересную мне тему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from threading import Thread

def fun(a):
   p = a + 10
   return p

p1 = Thread(target = fun, args = (4,))
p2 = Thread(target = fun, args = (10,))
p3 = Thread(target = fun, args = (15,))

p1.start()
p2.start()
p3.start()
```

Comment: `.join` потокам надо тоже не забывать делать, иначе порождённые потоки могут завершиться сразу с окончанием работы основного потока. В вашем случае это может и не важно, поскольку потоки почти ничего не делают и, наверное, успеют отработать до окончания основного потока, а вот если бы они делали что-то существенное, то это было бы важно.